# How does this proof work that shows a function is onto?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Is the function $p:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $p(x) = 3x^2 - 4x + 5$ onto?
>
> Let $y = 3x^2 - 4x + 5$, we want to know if we can always express $x$ in terms of $y$. Rearranging the equation, we find
>
> $$ 3x^2 - 4x + (5 - y) = 0 \tag{1} $$
>
> We want this equation to be solvable over $\mathbb{R}$, that is, we want its solutions to be real. This requires its discriminant to be nonnegative. So we need:
>
> $$ (-4)^2 - 4 \cdot 3 \cdot (5 - y) = 12y - 44 \ge 0 \tag{2} $$
>
> We have solutions only when $y \ge \frac{11}{3}$. This means, when $y \lt \frac{11}{3}$ we cannot find an $x$-value such that $p(x) = y$. Therefore, $p$ is not onto.

I understand that the rearranged equation in $(1)$ is a quadratic, so we need to have its discriminator non-negative in order to have real solutions.

But what's happening in $(2)$ and how do they then solve for $\frac{11}{3}$, this part I don't get.

Comment: (2) is the discriminant $b^2 - 4ac$, which must be $\ge 0$ for $3x^2 - 4x + (5-y) = 0$ to have a real solution $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof begins by attempting to find the pre-image of $p(x)$, i.e. given any $y \in \mathbb R$, you want the set of $x$ such that $p(x)=y$. If this set is never empty, then $p(x)$ is onto.

So solving (1) gives the required set of $x$'s. But to know whether any solutions exist in $\mathbb{R}$, we need to check that the discriminant is non-negative. This is done in (2), and for the discriminant to be non-negative, (after some algebra) we ultimately need to satisfy the inequality $12y-44 \geq 0$.

However, this inequality can't be satisfied if $y<\frac{11}{3}$, i.e. the there are no (real) values of $x$ that give $p(x)=y$ if you choose $y$ to be any value less than $\frac{11}{3}$. In other words, $p(x)$ only maps onto $[\frac{11}{3},\infty)$, and not the entire real line.

Answer (score 0):

$$12y - 44 \geq 0$$

Add $44$ to both sides:

$$12y \geq 44$$

Now divide both sides by $4$:

$$3y \ge 11$$

Divide both sides by $3$:

$$y \geq \frac{11}{3}.$$

Remark:

Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, where $a \neq 0$, we know for sure that this function is not onto as this function has a turning point. If the turning point is a maximum, any value greater than the maximum value has no preimage. Similar, if the turning point attains the minimal value.

Answer (score 0):

First let us understand the definition of onto:
A function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is defined as *onto*(surjective), if the images of $X$ i.e. all the elements of $Y$ is an image of $X$.

To state it in simple terms: There should be at least one element of $X$ mapping to all the elements of $Y$.

Now in your example, as no element in $X$ maps to any number $y < \frac{11}{3}$, our function is **not onto**.

The function is also not *one-to-one*(injective).[Graph](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiIzeF4yLTR4KzUiLCJjb2xvciI6IiMwMDAwMDAifSx7InR5cGUiOjEwMDAsIndpbmRvdyI6WyItMjMuMzIiLCIyOC42OCIsIi00LjExOTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OSIsIjI3Ljg4Il19XQ--)

So the function is not bijective.